# Apache httpd libtool empty include

Tags: macos, httpd

I'm trying to build httpd 2.4.3 from source. I've compiled APR and APR-util (with openssl), but libtool is putting an empty include directory in the command, and it breaks. For example:

```
/usr/local/web/httpd-apr/build-1/libtool --silent --mode=link gcc -std=gnu99 -g -O2 -I              -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib   -o ab  ab.lo       /usr/local/web/httpd-apr-util/lib/libaprutil-1.la -lexpat -liconv /usr/local/web/httpd-apr/lib/libapr-1.la -lpthread  
i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2: ab: No such file or directory
make[1]: *** [ab] Error 1
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

If you look at the `-I` flag, you'll see that it is followed by several blank spaces before `-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib`. As a result, I get the "no such file or directory" error. I've tried running libtool myself without the mysterious `-I`, but that doesn't work for everything. Am I missing a configuration option or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the `-I` was from `EXTRA_CFLAGS`. Setting `CFLAGS` before running configure worked. I'm leaving this up in case anyone else runs into the same problem.